# opening or allowing a port in a domain programatically

Tags: c++, winapi, dns, port, windows-firewall

I want to send data from network behind proxy and firewall to cloud over TCP and port x. There might be scenario that the port is not allowed/opened over the firewall. Can i open the port pragmatically (c++)? This has to be done at the org level. I found a sample code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726(v=VS.85).aspx) but while trying to connect to the firewall in method `WindowsFirewallInitialize()` I am getting an error:

> There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.

Comment: note:i am running the program on a machine which i am connected through remote desktop connection

Comment: After a little research I found there are two firewall systems in place. One is windows firewall - acting on my local machine. Then there is org firewall controlling the inbound and outbound traffics to and from any Ip/port. So if we have to send data to any ip outside the org domain, we need to allow that ip and port on the firewall.

So the question is - can it be done through c++ program.

Comment: another update - the link I shared above is to manipulate local windows firewall. two quick instructions for the codes to work and not getting the error- firewall should be running, and the user should have admin access to the machine.
Secondly the org level firewall (proxy server) can not be managed through programs.